# Optaplanner built-in hard constraints continuous planning

Tags: optimization, optaplanner

Currently I'm doing continuous planning, and I have two entities, one is the machine and the other one is the order.
The machine contains a planning list variable and the order has an inverse shadow variable pointing to the machine.
I want to add a built-in hard constraint to limit to what machines a certain order can go, however I cannot use the ValueRangeProvider in the machine entity to filter out the orders list because it cannot be used inside an entity. Is there another way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, entity-dependent value ranges do not work with planning list variables. There is no plan to support that in the near future.

You can still achieve the desired built-in hard constraint by using [filtered move selection](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#filteredMoveSelection).

You'll typically need three `SelectionFilter` implementations, one for each move type. I assume you want to use the Construction Heuristic phase, which has the `ListAssignMove` and you want to have both `ListChangeMove` and `ListSwapMove` in your Local Search phase.

Then, you'll need an advanced solver configuration to apply those filter.

I've tried this approach on the TaskAssignment example to replace the `noMissingSkills` constraint in the `TaskAssigningConstraintProvider` and make it a built-in hard constraint using move filtering. This is what I ended up with:

### Filters

These should also work in your case if you just change `Employee` to `Machine`, `Task` to `Order` and rename the `isTaskAllowed()` to better fit your domain.

```java
public class TaskAssignMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<TaskAssignment, ListAssignMove<TaskAssignment>> {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<TaskAssignment> scoreDirector, ListAssignMove<TaskAssignment> move) {
        return ((Employee) move.getDestinationEntity()).isTaskAllowed(((Task) move.getMovedValue()));
    }
}
```

```java
public class TaskChangeMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<TaskAssignment, ListChangeMove<TaskAssignment>> {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<TaskAssignment> scoreDirector, ListChangeMove<TaskAssignment> move) {
        return ((Employee) move.getDestinationEntity()).isTaskAllowed(((Task) move.getMovedValue()));
    }
}
```

```java
public class TaskSwapMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<TaskAssignment, ListSwapMove<TaskAssignment>> {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<TaskAssignment> scoreDirector, ListSwapMove<TaskAssignment> move) {
        return ((Employee) move.getLeftEntity()).isTaskAllowed(((Task) move.getRightValue())) &&
                ((Employee) move.getRightEntity()).isTaskAllowed(((Task) move.getLeftValue()));
    }
}
```

### The new `isTaskAllowed()` method on `Employee`

This implements the hard constraint. Replace the logic to reject `Order`s that must not be assigned to the given `Machine`.

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class Employee extends AbstractPersistable implements Labeled {

    ...

    public boolean isTaskAllowed(Task task) {
        return skillSet.containsAll(task.getTaskType().getRequiredSkillList());
    }

    ...
}
```

### Solver config

Pretty much copy-paste this. Just change the `variableName` attribute value (I guess to `"orders"`) and the filters' class names.

```xml
  <constructionHeuristic>
    <queuedValuePlacer>
      <valueSelector id="1" variableName="tasks"/>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <filterClass>org.optaplanner.examples.taskassigning.domain.solver.TaskAssignMoveFilter</filterClass>
        <valueSelector mimicSelectorRef="1"/>
      </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedValuePlacer>
  </constructionHeuristic>
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <filterClass>org.optaplanner.examples.taskassigning.domain.solver.TaskChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
      </changeMoveSelector>
      <swapMoveSelector>
        <filterClass>org.optaplanner.examples.taskassigning.domain.solver.TaskSwapMoveFilter</filterClass>
      </swapMoveSelector>
    </unionMoveSelector>
  </localSearch>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the example! I had done it with the changeMoveSelector and swapMoveSelector, however i didn't add in the constructionHeuristic and still had to keep the constraints, but with your example it is working like a charm now. Thank you once again!

Comment: Hello, yurloc. In the Project Job Scheduling example, I want to keep the resource used by an Allocation the same as the resources of its predecessor Allocation. I use a similar filterClass but it doesn't work. I created a new question in the following link, could you please help me out? Thank you in advance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73505568/how-to-keep-the-resource-the-same-as-the-predecessor-allocation-in-project-job-s

Comment: Hi, yurloc. I think I solved the problem, just made a small mistake before. Thank you!